# How can I delete a folder from a git branch?

Tags: git, version-control

[image: the folder to be deleted]

I have already written `git rm --cached -r 'hw 1, try 1'`, nevertheless the folder stayed in the master branch.

Comment: After you remove it, you have to `git commit` that removal. And then `git push` to your remote.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this steps:

```
1) git rm -r 'hw 1, try 1'
2) git commit -m "your-comment-for-deletion"
3) git push origin <your-branch-name>
```

Note that if you just want to remove it from your git repository but not delete it from your local filesystem you should replace step number 1 with:

```
git rm -r --cached 'hw 1, try 1'
```

** If the above steps doesn't work, try to force the deletion of the directory:

```
git rm -rf 'hw 1, try 1'
```